# How to use INSTR() and SUBSTR()

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have a small example, of how to use `INSTR()` and `SUBSTR()`
My example:

```
String = 'test = "2"';
apostrophe1:= INSTR(String,'"',1,1);
apostrophe2:= INSTR(String,'"',1,2);
equal:= INSTR(String,'=',1,1);

f_property_name:= SUBSTR(V1,1,equal-2);
f_property_value:= SUBSTR(V1,(apostrophe1)+1,(apostrophe2)-2);
dbms_output.put_line(f_property_name||' = '||f_property_value);
```

I wish to have a result like: `test = 3`.
But my result is: `test = 3"`
Can someone explain where is my mistake?

Comment: You should learn to use the regexp functions, particularly `regexp_replace()` for this one.  Clearly the problem is an off-by-one error and should be easy to fix by subtracting 1 from something.

Comment: I forgot to mention. I tried too, youre ideea but is not working. I have the same result, even substracting with -4. For this reason I can't understand why is not working.
That string is come from a line of text file, maybe from here is the problem.

Comment: f_property_value:= REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(V1,(apostrophe1)+1,(apostrophe2)-2),'"','');  Thanks, man!Even you subtract my respect point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f_property_value:= REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(V1,(apostrophe1)+1,(apostrophe2)-2),'"','');
```

It is working with this.